# What does "/fi/a" do in this sed command/script?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

What does `/fi/a` do in the following?

```bsh
sudo sed -i.bak '/fi/a #xrdp multiple users configuration \n xfce-session \n' /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

It looks like it finds any line containing "fi" and then writes the string to the next line. Unfortunately, while they appear to be targeting just "fi" it is also applied to lines containing the word "profile" in this file.

The command is recommended here and in several other places:
https://medium.com/@vivekteega/how-to-setup-an-xrdp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-89f7e205bd4e

Answer (score 5):

The command is doing exactly what you said. It will append the string to each *first* occurrence of `fi` in a line. But since it is just looking for `fi`, it will also match "pro**fi**le" or "**fi**nite" or "veri**fi**able" or any other string that contains `fi`.

To avoid this, you can specify that it should only match at word boundaries (`\b`). With GNU `sed` (possibly others as well, the `\b` is relatively portable):

```
$ cat file
profile
finite
verifiable
foo bar fi

$ $ sed '/\bfi\b/a #xrdp multiple users configuration \n xfce-session \n' file 
profile
finite
verifiable
foo bar fi
#xrdp multiple users configuration 
 xfce-session
```

As you can see, only the stand-alone `fi` was changed. So you can change your original command to:

```
sudo sed -i.bak '/\bfi\b/a #xrdp multiple users configuration \n xfce-session \n' /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

If your `sed` flavor doesn't know `\b` but supports `-E`, you can also do:

```
sed -E '/(^| )fi( |$)/a #xrdp multiple users configuration \n xfce-session \n' file
```

However, as far as I know, most sed implementations cannot deal with `\n`, so this almost certainly requires GNU sed anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Does this fall under regular expressions? Any recommended reading for future reference?

Comment: @iyrin yes, this is a regular expression. https://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good place to start.

Comment: That `a #xrdb` with the text on the same line is GNU-specific. POSIXly, you need to put the text on the following line (after `a \\`). POSIXly, you can and generally do add more than one line, you just need to terminate all but the last line with a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match a `fi` on a single line, you could anchor it with `^` (start of the line) and `$` (end of the line). There are also some unnecessary space characters before and after `\n` in your string you could remove.

```
sudo sed -i.bak '/^fi$/a #xrdp multiple users configuration\nxfce-session\n' /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```